# Apply feature selection to new X data set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

First time poster! I'm *really* new to data science and have decided to enter a competition. I have writen some code to select the top 10% of features from my training dataset X (9999 rows, 2000 columns).

What I can't figure out is how to apply this same feature selection to a new validation dataset X_val so that I can predict Y_val using my AdaBoostRegressor. Any help would be appreciated! Using the code below I get an error about how X_val has too many features.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import savetxt
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression

# Load training data
X = genfromtxt('train_X_final.csv', delimiter=',')
Y = genfromtxt('train_Y_final.csv', delimiter=',')

# Feature Selection
X_new = SelectPercentile(score_func = f_regression, percentile = 10).fit_transform(X, Y)

# Create regression object
clf = AdaBoostRegressor(n_estimators = 100, loss = 'exponential')

# Load validation data
X_val = genfromtxt('val_X_final.csv', delimiter=',')

# Train dataset
clf.fit(X_new, Y)

Y_pred = clf.predict(X_val)

# Crop impossible values
Y_pred[Y_pred < 0] = 0
Y_pred[Y_pred > 600] = 600

savetxt("Y_predict_feat.csv", Y_pred, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to save you feature selector object and call its `transform` method on the validation set like so:

```
selector = SelectPercentile(score_func = f_regression, percentile = 10)
X_new = selector.fit_transform(X, Y)
X_val = selector.transform(genfromtxt('val_X_final.csv', delimiter=','))

clf.fit(X_new, Y)
Y_pred = clf.predict(X_val)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Unfortunately it didn't get me a better score in the competition than just adaboost by itself. Back to the drawing board...